# Unwanted URL exception error (could be adware)

Tags: vb.net, url, jscript

I am trying to create a simple polygon via vb.net and when I try to post it to the output stream I get an error. this is happening even when I created a new program. I did a lot of online search but could not find a solution. Some people talk about addons. I checked my IE nothing shows up on the addons window. I am lost now. I really do not understand what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Below is the error message I get :

> *Microsoft JScript runtime error: Exception thrown and not caught*

and it opens up the following:

```
m = url.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?([a-z0-9\-_]+?)\.(co|org|net|com|gov|name|arpa|mil|edu|biz|mobi|aero|asia|cat|coop|info|int|jobs|museum|pro|tel|travel|xxx|[a-z][a-z]|(co|edu|gov|net|org|com)\.[a-z][a-z])(\/|$)/i);
    if (m === null) {
        if(url.indexOf('dnserror') != -1 || url.indexOf('ieframe.dll') != -1)
        {   
            var loc_sp = url.split("#");
            if(loc_sp[1] && loc_sp[1] != '')
                window.location = "http://404bucks.com/landing/?uid="+affiliate+subid+"&domainname="+loc_sp[1];
        }
        else
            throw 'Not a valid URL: ' + url;
    }
    if(m[2] == "co" && url.indexOf('bbc') != -1)
        return "bbc";
    else if(m[2] == "yahoo" && url.indexOf('omg') != -1)
        return "omg";

    return m[2];
}
```

The "throw not a valid url" part is highlighted. I also do not know what is that 404buckx website or where is coming from.

the following is the code I use in a *`simple.aspx`* file :

```
    Dim bmp As Bitmap
    bmp = New Bitmap(200, 300)
    Dim gr As Graphics
    gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    gr.Clear(Color.Transparent)


    Dim pts() As Point = { _
        New Point(10, 10), New Point(100, 50), _
        New Point(190, 10), New Point(190, 250), _
        New Point(100, 298), New Point(10, 250)}

    Dim brred As Brush
    brred = Brushes.Red

    gr.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, pts)
    gr.FillPolygon(brred, pts)

    bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Comment: Hi guys, I do not know how many of you have read the post. But for those who have I think I am almost certain that this is some sort of adware/trojan or something.  I am trying to figure out a way to get rid of it. It won't let me update malware bytes either. Will keep you posted if I do find the problem. Thanks~!

Comment: Hmm... `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Exception thrown and not caught.` tells you exactly what is wrong. You've used `throw` but there is no `catch` block which could receive the thrown error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the error is finally gone. I ran spybot and malwarebytes on my computer. Removed whatever they asked me to. Guess that worked. Though I still cannot install an anti-virus on my computer, it blue screens. Whatever it is, is still there. Shifted course if you want to say so. Guess I will reinstall windows. For now though I can code :)